# how to use pandas filter with IQR

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing, iqr

Is there a built-in way to do filtering on a column by IQR(i.e.  values between Q1-1.5IQR and Q3+1.5IQR)?
also, any other possible generalized filtering in pandas suggested will be appreciated.

Answer (score 75):

As far as I know, the most compact notation seems to be brought by the `query` method.

```
# Some test data
np.random.seed(33454)
df = (
    # A standard distribution
    pd.DataFrame({'nb': np.random.randint(0, 100, 20)})
        # Adding some outliers
        .append(pd.DataFrame({'nb': np.random.randint(100, 200, 2)}))
        # Reseting the index
        .reset_index(drop=True)
    )

# Computing IQR
Q1 = df['nb'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df['nb'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1

# Filtering Values between Q1-1.5IQR and Q3+1.5IQR
filtered = df.query('(@Q1 - 1.5 * @IQR) <= nb <= (@Q3 + 1.5 * @IQR)')
```

Then we can plot the result to check the difference. We observe that the outlier in the left boxplot (the cross at 183) does not appear anymore in the filtered series.

```
# Ploting the result to check the difference
df.join(filtered, rsuffix='_filtered').boxplot()
```

[image: Comparison before and after filterinf]

*Since this answer I've written a [post](https://www.back2code.me/2017/08/outliers) on this topic were you may find more information.*

Comment: My DF has many columns and I just want to plot one column of that (for ex. "nb"). The `df.join(filtered, rsuffix='_filtered').boxplot()` won't work for this.

Comment: This solution could be made pointlessly shorter with `Q1, Q3 = df['nb'].quantile([.25, .75])`

Answer (score 29):

Another approach using [Series.between()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
iqr = df['col'][df['col'].between(df['col'].quantile(.25), df['col'].quantile(.75), inclusive=True)]
```

Drawn out:

```
# Select the first quantile
q1 = df['col'].quantile(.25)

# Select the third quantile
q3 = df['col'].quantile(.75)

# Create a mask inbeetween q1 & q3
mask = df['col'].between(q1, q3, inclusive=True)

# Filtering the initial dataframe with a mask
iqr = df.loc[mask, 'col']
```

Comment: To be clear, this returns the values between the 25th and 75th percentiles (Q1 and Q3). It _does not_ filter on Q1-1.5IQR and Q3+1.5IQR. So, if you're wanting to use Q1-1.5IQR and Q3+1.5IQR for outlier-classification: use one of the other soultions here.

Answer (score 10):

This will give you the subset of `df` which lies in the IQR of column `column`:

```py
def subset_by_iqr(df, column, whisker_width=1.5):
    """Remove outliers from a dataframe by column, including optional 
       whiskers, removing rows for which the column value are 
       less than Q1-1.5IQR or greater than Q3+1.5IQR.
    Args:
        df (`:obj:pd.DataFrame`): A pandas dataframe to subset
        column (str): Name of the column to calculate the subset from.
        whisker_width (float): Optional, loosen the IQR filter by a
                               factor of `whisker_width` * IQR.
    Returns:
        (`:obj:pd.DataFrame`): Filtered dataframe
    """
    # Calculate Q1, Q2 and IQR
    q1 = df[column].quantile(0.25)                 
    q3 = df[column].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    # Apply filter with respect to IQR, including optional whiskers
    filter = (df[column] >= q1 - whisker_width*iqr) & (df[column] <= q3 + whisker_width*iqr)
    return df.loc[filter]                                                     

# Example for whiskers = 1.5, as requested by the OP
df_filtered = subset_by_iqr(df, 'column_name', whisker_width=1.5)
```

Comment: please update your formula as IQR is 25th and 75th percentile values. But while removing we remove values less than q1-1.5IQR or greater thatn q3+1.5IQR

Comment: @MNA do you to change `>=` and `<=`    to    `>` and `<`?

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: Ah, you mean to include the whiskers of width `1.5`. I've included these as an option now, as this is a hyperparameter which very dependent on the dataset.

Comment: Thanks. I asked this because if you use whisker_width = 0, then you will always end up removing some of your data. Also, whisker_width = 1.5 is standard practice.

Answer (score 10):

Find the 1st and 3rd quartile using `df.quantile` and then use a mask on the dataframe.
In case you want to remove them, use `no_outliers` and invert the condition in the mask to get `outliers`.

```py
Q1 = df.col.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df.col.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
no_outliers = df.col[(Q1 - 1.5*IQR < df.BMI) &  (df.BMI < Q3 + 1.5*IQR)]
outliers = df.col[(Q1 - 1.5*IQR >= df.BMI) |  (df.BMI >= Q3 + 1.5*IQR)]
```

Comment: what is `df.BMI` ?

Answer (score 5):

Another approach uses Series.clip:

```
q = s.quantile([.25, .75])
s = s[~s.clip(*q).isin(q)]
```

here are details:

```
s = pd.Series(np.randon.randn(100))
q = s.quantile([.25, .75])  # calculate lower and upper bounds
s = s.clip(*q)  # assigns values outside boundary to boundary values
s = s[~s.isin(q)]  # take only observations within bounds
```

Using it to filter a whole dataframe `df` is straightforward:

```
def iqr(df, colname, bounds = [.25, .75]):
    s = df[colname]
    q = s.quantile(bounds)
    return df[~s.clip(*q).isin(q)]
```

Note: the method excludes the boundaries themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the below code, also, by calculating IQR. Based on the IQR, lower and upper bound, it will replace the value of outliers presented in each column. this code will go through each columns in data-frame and work one by one by filtering the outliers alone, instead of going through all the values in rows for finding outliers.

Function:

```
    def mod_outlier(df):
        df1 = df.copy()
        df = df._get_numeric_data()


        q1 = df.quantile(0.25)
        q3 = df.quantile(0.75)

        iqr = q3 - q1

        lower_bound = q1 -(1.5 * iqr) 
        upper_bound = q3 +(1.5 * iqr)


        for col in col_vals:
            for i in range(0,len(df[col])):
                if df[col][i] < lower_bound[col]:            
                    df[col][i] = lower_bound[col]

                if df[col][i] > upper_bound[col]:            
                    df[col][i] = upper_bound[col]    


        for col in col_vals:
            df1[col] = df[col]

        return(df1)
```

Function call:

```
df = mod_outlier(df)
```

Comment: I got an error: NameError: name 'col_vals' is not defined for that.

Comment: col_vals is nothing but the columns avalailable , make one entry for that, or else replace col_vals with df.columns in the code