# How to remove outliers in a certain category of data?

Tags: python, statistics, boxplot, data-cleaning

[boxplot for the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL5W5.png)

```
plot = sns.boxplot(y = 'charges', x = 'smoker' , data = df)
```

I was trying to remove outliers for the "no" category here. For which I filtered the no values

```
no_charges = d[d.smoker == 'no'].charges
```

Calculated the IQR

```
Q1 = no_charges.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = no_charges.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3-Q1
```

Filtered the outliers

```
da = df.copy()
no = da[da.smoker == 'no']
rem = no[(no.charges > (Q3 + 1.5*IQR)) | (no.charges < (Q3 - 1.5*IQR))]
```

But I am facing issue when I try to drop the desired data from the main table

```
da.drop[[(no.charges > (Q3 + 1.5*IQR)) | (no.charges < (Q3 - 1.5*IQR))], inplace=True]
```

Can we do it this way? If not then how to filter the values?

Comment: what issue you are facing ? 
it would be better if you include error message as well.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-183-e419bf208ec7>", line 1
    da.drop[[(no.charges > (Q3 + 1.5*IQR)) | (no.charges < (Q3 - 1.5*IQR))], inplace=True]
          ^                                                                          
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

It shows syntax error at (inplace = True), but it is correct syntax i believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the outliers

```
df = da[~((no_charges < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(no_charges > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

You can refer this answer for detailed explanation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50461938/1727543