# Inverting logic for Bitwise operator (&, | ) on columns with objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a continuation of [the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461349/how-to-remove-outlier-from-dataframe-using-iqr) used in this question.

Say we have a dataframe

```
    Make    Model   Year    HP    Cylinders Transmission  MPG-H MPG-C   Price
0   BMW 1 Series M  2011    335.0   6.0      MANUAL         26  19     46135
1   BMW 1 Series    2011    300.0   6.0      MANUAL         28  19     40650
2   BMW 1 Series    2011    300.0   6.0      MANUAL         28  20     36350
3   BMW 1 Series    2011    230.0   6.0      MANUAL         28  18     29450
4   BMW 1 Series    2011    230.0   6.0      MANUAL         28  18     34500
...
```

Using the interquartile range (IQR) (i.e middle 50%), I created 2 variables, `upper` and `lower`. The specific calculation isn't important in this discussion, but to give an example of `upper`:

```
Year          2029.50
HP             498.00
Cylinders        9.00
MPG-H           42.00
MPG-C           31.00
Price        75291.25
```

As expected, it only calculates values for columns that have int64 values.

When I want to filter out values that lie outside of the IQR,

```
correct_df = df[~((df < lower) |(df > upper)).any(axis=1)]
```

it gives me the right answer. However, when I invert the logic to use `&` instead of `|`, I get an empty dataframe. Here is the code:

```
another_df = df[((df >= lower) & (df <= upper)).all(axis=1)]
```

Which gives the results, but can be fixed by converting the index of `upper`/`lower` into a list ('lst'):

```
Make    Model   Year    HP  Cylinders   Transmission    Drive Mode  MPG-H   MPG-C   Price

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

another_df = df[((df[lst] >= lower) & (df[lst] <= upper)).all(axis=1)]
```

It seems like `&` and `|` behave differently for non-numerical columns? Why does that happen?

Comment: I don't think you should be switching from `any` to `all` when you invert logic. Using de Moivre, removing the not operator and switching & for | is enough to make the logic equivalent so whatever comes after that should be the same.

Comment: * de Morgan, not de Moivre, sorry

Answer (score 1):

`&` and `|` behave just as you'd expect; they're not the problem. They problem is that you're use `all` in the code that doesn't work, but in the code that does work, you're using `any`.

In the first example you say "select all rows where **any** column of the row is *less than `lower`* OR is *greater than `upper`*"

In the second example you say "select all rows where **ALL** columns of the row are *greater than or equal to `lower`* OR are *less than or equal to `upper`*".

Change `all` to `any` and you should be fine.