# custom function to extract and visualize outliers in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

For the dataframe below,I want to write a function that

I. extract the outliers for each column and export the output as a csv file (I need help with this one)

II. visualize using boxplot and export as pdf file

Outlier definition:  as boundaries ±3 standard deviations from the mean

OR

as being any point of data that lies over 1.5 IQRs below the first quartile (Q1) or above the third quartile (Q3)in a data set.
High = (Q3) + 1.5 IQR
Low = (Q1) – 1.5 IQR

See below for the dataset and my attempt :

```
# dataset 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
  
# intialise data of lists.
data = {'region':['R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2','R1','R1','R1','R2','R2'],
         'cost':[120.05, 181.90, 10.21, 133.01, 311.19,2003.4,112.4,763.2,414.8,812.5],
        'commission':[110.21, 191.12, 190.21,15.31, 245.09,63.41,811.3,10.34, 153.10, 311.17],
        'salary':[10022,19910, 19113,449999, 25519,140.29, 291.07, 390.22, 245.09, 4122.62],
        'revenue':[14029, 29100, 39022, 24509, 412271,110.21, 191.12, 190.21, 12.00, 245.09],
        'tax':[120.05, 181.90, 10.34, 153.10, 311.17,52119,32991,52883,69359,57835],
         'debt':[100.22,199.10, 191.13,199.99, 255.19,41218, 52991,1021,69152,79355],
         'income': [43211,7672991,56881,211,77342,100.22,199.10, 191.13,199.99, 255.19],
          'rebate': [31.21,429.01,538.18,621.58,6932.5,120.05, 181.90, 10.34, 153.10, 311.17],
        'scale':['small','small','small','mid','mid','large','large','mid','large','small']
        }
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# Print the output.
df

############## my attempt ####################


def outlier_extractor(data):
    # select numeric columns
    numeric_columns = data.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.tolist()
    #(I)Extract and export outliers as csv..... I need help with this one
    
    #(II) boxplot visualization 
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 9))
    
    for i, variable in enumerate(numeric_columns):
        plt.subplot(4, 4, i + 1)
        plt.boxplot(data[variable],whis=1.5)
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.title(variable)
    plt.savefig('graph_outliers.pdf')
    plt.show()

# driver code 
outlier_extractor(df)
```

Please comment and share your full code. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have to explain your definition of "out-layer"

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco:  You can use outlier High = (Q3) + 1.5 IQR
Low = (Q1) – 1.5 IQR or Outlier boundaries ±3 standard deviations from the mean

Comment: OK got it. So you want detect outlier in the measurement, not in the entire row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782063/how-to-use-pandas-filter-with-iqr
duplicated question from this one

Comment: @lucky6qi I want to export as csv file, it is not duplicated, I want to include in a function

Comment: then you need df[[col_name]].to_csv("...") added

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco, Yes outliers value in each column and export as a csv file

Comment: @lucky6qi, I want filter for all numeric columns, the link you shared is just for an individual column, hence why I am using a function

Comment: you can have a for loop to go over all columns, and using the function in the link for every column.

Comment: @lucky6qi. Please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def outlier_extractor(data):
    numeric_data = data.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
    Q1, Q3 = numeric_data.quantile(.25), numeric_data.quantile(.75)
    IQR = Q3-Q1
    numeric_data[:] = np.where((numeric_data > Q3+1.5*IQR)|(numeric_data < Q1-1.5*IQR), np.nan, numeric_data)
    numeric_data.apply(lambda series:series.dropna().to_csv(series.name+".csv"))
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 9))
    for i, variable in enumerate(numeric_columns):
        plt.subplot(4, 4, i + 1)
        plt.boxplot(data[variable],whis=1.5)
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.title(variable)
    #plt.savefig('graph_outliers.pdf')
    plt.show()

outlier_extractor(df)
```

Note that the `apply` function saves each filtered column in one different `csv` file. From your description I though that this was your task.

Note also that you don't need the `seaborn` package

EDIT

To export all the filtered dataframe with missing values replacing the ouliers you have to replace the `to_csv` row with:

```
numeric_data.to_excel("filtered_numeric_data.xlsx")
```

Comment: works good, however, I want the output as one dataframe, then exported as a single csv file. Your code currently exports multiple csv files. Thanks

Comment: With corresponding column names

Comment: How can I export a dataframe with missing values?  You want to replace the outliers with `NaN` for example?

Comment: Yes. You can repalce with `NaN` or alternatively highlight the outliers with a red color

Comment: `csv` format is a text only format, so you can't specify anything about the style, font, color etc... The only solution is to drop outlier with `NaN`.

Comment: True, I forgot that about `.csv`, you can highlight and then export as `.xlsx`

Comment: for this you will need the `openpyxl` package. Do you know haow to use it?

Comment: If its not too much, you can adjust the code to export as `xlsx`,otherwise, you can just export the dataframe with with outlier values  and non outlier values as  `NaN`  in `csv`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247115/discussion-between-salvatore-daniele-bianco-and-rayx500).