# How to remove the top and bottom e.g., 10% of data from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How can you filter a DataFrame in pandas by selecting rows that fall within the 10th and 90th percentiles based on a specific column and then remove these filtered rows from the original DataFrame?

Code Example:

```
# Create a sample DataFrame
data = {
    'A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 172, 183, 92, 105, 120],
    'B': [3, 14, 27, 33, 41, 55, 66, 75, 88, 92]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Filter the DataFrame based on the 10th and 90th percentiles of column 'A'
q10 = df['A'].quantile(0.1)
q90 = df['A'].quantile(0.9)

filtered_df = df[(df['A'] > q10) & (df['A'] < q90)]
```

Issue: filtered_df doesn't really remove entry below 10th percentile and above 90th percentile.

EDIT: Output should have 8 rows i.e. 80 percentile of the data.

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: "*Output should have 8 rows i.e. 80 percentile of the data.*" -> that's not how percentiles work

Comment: Agreed, I want to remove outlier, but, in some case, there aren't outliers and so above is what I am trying...

Comment: I answered below on how to remove the top/bottom 10%. If you want to remove outliers, use a well known method, like the [values outside of 1.5*IQR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34782063/16343464).

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your title since it implied that `.quantile` was returning incorrect results, which it is not.

Comment: I should also note that just because something is the top or bottom 10% of your data, doesn't mean it's an outlier that should be removed. Take care to ensure you have sufficient justification to remove potentially informative data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using percentiles won't guarantee having a fixed number of rows.

It rather looks like you want to take 80% of the ranked values.

Using [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) with `'first'` and [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
m = (df['A']
     .rank(method='first').sub(1)
     .between(0.1*len(df), 0.9*len(df),
              inclusive='left')
     )

out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
     A   B
1    0  14
2    0  27
3    0  33
4    0  41
5  172  55
7   92  75
8  105  88
9  120  92
```

Intermediates:

```
     A   B  rank      m
0    0   3   1.0  False
1    0  14   2.0   True
2    0  27   3.0   True
3    0  33   4.0   True
4    0  41   5.0   True
5  172  55   9.0   True
6  183  66  10.0  False
7   92  75   6.0   True
8  105  88   7.0   True
9  120  92   8.0   True
```

Comment: How does this work if hypothetically there is a NaN in the data?

Comment: nevermind, will check the documentation of rank

Comment: @rram in the case of ties like you have here, you need to be sure that you can justify dropping a particular row where A = 0 and not. What are you doing with the B column? Is dropping the row where B = 3 better than dropping the row where B = 14?

Comment: In general, better not drop anything. If really outliers are an issue, make sure to use a reliable method as I suggested in comments ([1.5*IQR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34782063/16343464)). And finally, [removing outliers doesn't prevent your from having outliers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70849524/16343464) ;)